# The MVC error on load HTML. ViewData item that has the key 'MY KEY' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I am doing an MVC APP. For this example..

In my definition of my `DropDownListFor` I defined something like this.

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSystem, Model.Systems, new { @class = "form-control listbox",id="Origin" })
```

My Model is loaded in the Controller, where it loads `Model.System` under certain circumstances. Model.System is of type `List<SelectListItem>`

The option selected is in `model.SelectedSystem` that is a `string type`. That works fine...

The problem i am facing is when `Model.System` is null.

My Controller looks like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var apiEntitySyncViewModel = new ApiEntitySyncViewModel
            {
                Systems = _entitySyncService.GetEnvironments(),
            };
            return View(apiEntitySyncViewModel);
        }
```

On running appears the message `The ViewData item that has the key SelectedSystemOrigin is of type System.String but must be of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

How can I draw an empty DropDownListFor without having that mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var apiEntitySyncViewModel = new ApiEntitySyncViewModel
   {
       Systems = _entitySyncService.GetEnvironments(),
  };
if(apiEntitySyncViewModel.Systems==null) apiEntitySyncViewModel.Systems = new List <SelectListItem>();

//or you can try
new List <SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem{ Value="0", Text ="Empty" } 


  return View(apiEntitySyncViewModel);
}
```